# in app purchase dialog not showing in android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented in-app-purchase. The issue is that the billing dialog `billingClient.launchBillingFlow` not showing in some devices. First I tested in android 8 and everything works good but when I tested in android 9 and the billing dialog is not showing.
Here is the code

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this).build();

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                    skuList.add(ITEM_SKU_diamond_500);
                    final SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                            if (skuDetailsList != null && billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                    String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                    String price = skuDetails.getPrice();

                                    final BillingFlowParams params = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                            .build();

                                    if (ITEM_SKU_diamond_500.equals(sku)) {
                                        premiumUpgradePrice = price;
                                        firstBtn500(params);

                                    }

                                    //clickHandler(skuDetails, sku);
                                }
                            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ERROR) {
                                Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });

                } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_TIMEOUT) {
                    Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Service timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Failed to connect to the billing client", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Disconnected from the client", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

```
 private void firstBtn500(final BillingFlowParams params) {

        firstPurchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "OK: 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//The toast message is showing.
// but the billing dialog is not showing

                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(DiamondsActivity.this, params);

            }
        });

    }
```

```
 @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

        if (purchases != null && billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                handlePurchases(purchase);
            }

        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchased Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

```
private void handlePurchases(final Purchase purchase) {

        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
           
            // Todo :Consume the purchase async
            ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();

            ConsumeResponseListener consumeResponseListener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull String purchaseToken) {

                    Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Purchase successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                        if (purchase.getSku().equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM_SKU_diamond_500)) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "Thank you for purchasing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            handleAdditionOfData(500);
                        } 

                    }

                }
            };

            billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);


        } else if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase pending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update it with this method:

```
 private void firstBtn500(final BillingFlowParams params) {
    
            firstPurchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(DiamondsActivity.this, "OK: 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
       BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                  .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                                  .build();
     int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, params);
    
                   
    
                }
            });
    
        }
```

Comment: I already have the same code. The problem is purchase dialog(which have item name and price) not showing

Comment: I also tried with your code but I'm still facing issue

Comment: Try my new answer.

Comment: I'm using version```3.0.0```. ```setSku``` can not resolve method

Comment: Still not working. I'm facing the issue only in Android 9.

Comment: check the logcat . Can you share it?

Comment: Update play service and check.

Comment: ```billingClient.launchBillingFlow(DiamondsActivity.this, params);``` I think this mehod is not calling or it's not responsing.

Comment: Check my answer. Can you check the response code? Just toast it and let me know it.

Comment: Yes, toast message is showing. but billing dialog is not

Comment: let me know the responseCode  value. Check my answer please.

Comment: ```com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult@cacd93f``` here is the value

Comment: is it an int value!! ? check here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Comment: ```responseCode.getDebugMessage()``` use this and get the message ``` item already owned```. But I consumed the purchase then why this showing item already owned

Comment: the purchase didn't consumed . I have got it. Remove the consume code out from Handlepurchase. Create a separate method. And call it under this line handlePurchases(purchase);
    on purchase update.

Comment: then clear playstore and your app data. and try it. It will work . :) Don't forget to accept it after work.

Comment: can you please update your answer how to create separate method?

Comment: check here and replace it by your need. https://textuploader.com/1x7g0

Comment: you can also do this. If responsecode is = to already purchase  then consume the purchase. it will asole start the flow. always try to keep the code neat and clean.  Because consume function will only call onetime.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970752/5038388 if the above solution did not work for you